# Query single table very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS odds_gl_ft (

    o_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    f_id INT NOT NULL,
    o_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    o_handicap DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    o_price_over DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL,
    o_price_under DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL,
    o_minute MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    o_team1_goals TINYINT NOT NULL,
    o_team2_goals TINYINT NOT NULL,
    o_total_goals TINYINT NOT NULL,
    o_profit_over DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    o_profit_under DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    o_al BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

I have 5 million + records in this table.

If I wanted to query the table (`SELECT * FROM odds_gl_ft`) it takes approx 2 minutes to do.

From an application perspective, there will be no reason why I'll need to extract all rows in this fashion, but it's made me think that perhaps my MySQL configuration, buffer sizing etc isn't optimized.

I've tried to reduce column types into their most efficient size (e.g. **TINYINT** where appropriate) but it's still around 2 minutes to query.

Is there a way to speed this up? Surely its not an indexing problem as I have no conditions on my query. Also I can't normalise the data as it's all quite unique.

Heidi Console says:

```
Duration for 1 query: 0.016 sec. (+ 155.594 sec. network) */
```

Comment: Can you share the duration time and fetch time ?

Comment: If your app doesn't need all columns, then why do you select all columns? Select only what you need, and put an index on those

Comment: @HoneyBadger The first suggestion, to select only columns needed, is good, because it reduces network latency.  The second index suggestion is unnecessary and won't help, because the table already has a clustered index on the primary key column, and there is no filtering.

Comment: Yes I know I should only select what I need and index appropriately but it was more a question of database configuration. Hypothetical

Comment: This time is used for network transfer. Nothing to optimize. Think, do you really need in ALL ROWS retrieving?

Comment: So the issue is more transferring the data from my private cloud instance, as it's so much. Ok thanks..

Comment: Do you use MySQL Workbench? Then you can take a look at execution plan and Query Stats.

Comment: Duration 0.016 sec means no issue from mysql. Only network issue

Answer (score 1):

Shoveling 5M rows takes time.  And may choke the client.  Maybe you should consider summing up some of the columns?  Or something else.  It will be faster to do things like that inside the server.

No configuration changes will help.